# perl dancer: foreach in template is only printing first value

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I have what should be a really simple problem in Dancer: I have an array of names, and I'd like to print each one in a template.  These names come from an outside source (not a database).  However, when I try to do a foreach over the list in the template, I only get the first value.

Code:

```
use Dancer;
use Template;

set 'template' => 'template_toolkit';

get '/' => sub {
    my @list = ("one","two","three");
    template 'list.tt', {
            'values' => @list,
    };
};
dance;
```

And template:

```
<ul>
    <%FOREACH item IN values %>
        <li><% item %></li>
    <%END%>
</ul>
```

This only outputs a list with a single item, "one". What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The expression `'values' => @list` expands to a list that contains `"values" "one" "two" "three"`, so you should try with a reference to the array instead:

```
template 'list.tt', {
        'values' => [@list],
};
```

The above still copies `@list` and returns a reference. If you want to fetch a reference to the already existing array, use `\@list`.

Answer (score 6):

I'll wager it's because you have to pass an array reference to the `'values'`:

```
template 'list.tt', {
        'values' => \@list,
};
```

Otherwise the list gets expanded and you're actually passing:

```
template 'list.tt', {
        'values' => $list[0],
        $list[1] => $list[2],
};
```